# Unable to test conditional rendering using react-testing-library and jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-testing

When I try to test conditional rendering of my component I get fail as result, even though it should pass.

Here is my component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const Carousel = ({ skeleton }) => {
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(skeleton !== undefined);

useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(false);
}, [])

    return (
    <>
        <Skeleton data-testid="skeleton-wrapper" hidden={!isLoading} />
        <CarouselItem data-testid="carousel-wrapper" hidden={isLoading} />
    </>
  )
}
```

And this is the TEST:

```
  it('should switch display property', async () => {
    renderWithTheme(
      <Carousel skeleton={<div>Skeleton children</div>}>
        <CarouselItem>Item 1</CarouselItem>
      </Carousel>,
    );

    expect(screen.getByTestId('skeleton-children')).not.toHaveAttribute('hidden');
    expect(screen.getByTestId('carousel-wrapper')).toHaveAttribute('hidden');
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByTestId('skeleton-wrapper')).toHaveAttribute('hidden'));
    expect(screen.getByTestId('carousel-wrapper')).toBeVisible();
  });
```

The test fail and it seems that skeleton-wrapper is already hidden, while carousel-wrapper already visibile.

The crazy part is that if I add a setTimeout, it works perfectly. So, if I add the code below, it works perfectly. I'd be appreciate if anyone has a clue that wants to share.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => { 
    setIsLoading(false);
    }, 1
   )
}, [])
```

It's weird if I add the code below, it works perfectly. I'd be appreciate if anyone has a clue that wants to share.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => { 
    setIsLoading(false);
    }, 1
   )
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting `isLoading` to false on component mount, then it's expected that it won't appear when component is rendered by the test.

And it appears with `setTimeout` because then it becomes `async` (read [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop)) instead of `sync` as it is now

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a carousel coming from the keen-slider library.
I've tried also to setIsLoading(false) inside created() (function provided by the library), but I get the same result: the assertions are false. It seems the skeleton is hidden since the beginning of the test.